# One of my dogs keeps pulling off and destroying my other dogs collar. Why does he do this?

Tags: dogs, chewing

I have a one and a half year old male Dalmatian cross who manages to remove the collar from my one year old  female staffy cross pug and then destroys it. He undoes it from the link then pulls it off and chews it up. Any chance he gets when we aren't looking he does this. We've been forced to put a chain collar on the staffy when we are at home and a regular collar on for walks but I don't like the idea of chains on dogs. 
Both dogs are from different adoption centres and we've had the male longer. The staffy/pug has only been with us for about a month. Other than this they get along fine and have no issues. 
I'm wondering if its a dominance thing for him to remind her that this is his house or something like that. Has anyone had similar issues when introducing a new dig into a house with one already there? Im confused and buying collars every week is a pain and expensive. I also don't want either dog to develop a complex. 
Thanks, Dane

Comment: Maybe he just sees it as a leather chew toy?

Answer (score 2):

He's doing it for fun. Bitey neck is a normal dog thing to do, chewing leather/fabric is a normal activity for a young active dog.  Leather that smells of his new best friend is even better.

BUT you need to be aware that dogs that do this can and have got caught up with tragic results.  The dog wearing the collar can be strangled.  The dog pulling on the collar can get his jaw caught in it and break his jawbone. This is not a safe way for dogs to behave.

Rather than put the staffie in a chain (definitely a choking risk if the dalmatian gets his jaws caught on it), you could either have the staffie not wear a collar at home for a while (this will probably stop once they get a bit older and more sensible) and reward with toys for not doing this, or if you are worried about her not having id, get a lot of cheap lightweight ribbon to hang the tag on, replace it whenever you need to and just put her 'real' collar on for walks.

If they play bitey neck on walks, you might want to swap to a body harness for walking just in case.  I know of someone whose dogs got caught playing bitey neck on a walk and only survived because they happened to have a gardening tool in their pocket to cut the collar (once the collar gets twisted and both dogs are fighting to breathe, it becomes difficult to undo buckles)

Answer (score 1):

Dogs who are friends will chew on each others necks as a form of play: if either dog is wearing a collar, it can become a casualty. ... If you apply the taste deterrent regularly to the collar, your dog will quickly learn to avoid putting his mouth there.